# Sending a message to the client on connection using node and socket io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

How do i send a message to a *specific* client, more specifically, the client that has just connected to the app without broadcasting to the rest of the visitors that are already on the site?

```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
   });
```

Seems to broadcast to everyone every time a new visitors connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.emit('greetings', { greeting:'hello, new visitor' });

    socket.on('greetingFromVisitor', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: This just requires the client to send the server a greet message on connection, right?
Am i right in saying this will only fire once? I'm having an issue at the moment where the client is receiving the welcome message over and over again every few minutes.

Comment: Nice one. I reversed the on connection event from the server, to the client, and everything is working swimmingly! :)